# Issue with serving files with fastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I'm trying to get a bytes file from a SFTP server and pass it as a file object to fastAPI to server.

```
        flo = BytesIO()
        srv.getfo(file, flo)
        kind = mimetypes.guess_type(file)
        flo.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(flo.read(), media_type=kind[0])
```

I get this error

```
AssertionError: 'aiofiles' must be installed to use FileResponse
```

So I tried streaming response and get an empty downloaded file.

```
return StreamingResponse(flo.read(), media_type=kind[0])
```

This is my front end just using a simple axios get and file download library

```
fileDownload(r.data, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My response from react needed to be responseType: 'blob' for it to get it correctly